# How can I call translation i18n in public/index.html?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

Reference : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization#custom-components

If I run `{{ $vuetify.lang.t('$vuetify.my-component.text') }}` in src/views/home.vue, it works

But If I run it in public/index.html, it does not works

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are the elements in the Vue scope you are trying to translate?

Comment: @hamzox I want to translate, title, meta description, meta keyword in the public/index.html. But my problem is public/index.html outside src folder

Comment: You should take a look at [`vue-meta`](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta).